# How to make timer stop on click

Tags: java, android, timer

My timer will stop when it reaches a certain number. Instead, I want it to stop on a button click. How do I do that?
This is what my code looks like currently:

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourpay);

final Timer t =new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        money = (PPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        t1.setText("$" + money); //Place your text data here
                        counter++;

                        //Place your stopping condition over here. Its important to have a stopping condition or it will go in an infinite loop. 
                        if(counter == HPDPS)
                            t.cancel(); 
                    }
            }); 
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

If possible I would like it to stop on button click AND when counter reaches HPDPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in your button's `onClickListener()`:

```
if (t != null)
    t.cancel();
```

and remove the stopping condition from the timer.

---

**Code Example (updated):**

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourpay);

final Timer t =new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                money = (PPS+Reserve);
                Reserve = (money);
                t1.setText("$" + money); //Place your text data here

                // Removed the stopping condition/counter

            }
        }); 
    }
}, 1000, 1000); // Do you really want to wait 1 second before executing the timer's code?  If not, change the 1st "1000" to a "0"


final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button_id); // Replace with your button's id
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (t != null)
            t.cancel();
        }
});
```

Comment: could you show me an example I could build off of? Like i said im really new to this so i dont really know how to format the onClickListener

Comment: thanks so much for all the help! There were a couple errors with the @override so i had to remove it? im not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Use a CountDownTimer.  When the button is clicked just stop the timer.

But for what you have just go ahead and create a button, set an OnClickListener on the button and then call timer.cancel() or whatever stops it inside on the onClick() method of your listener.